# Can I write this return in one line?

Tags: php, sql-server, shortcode

I work with databases in PHP and often fetch data from one. My question is: Can I write this in one line?

```
$res = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
return $res['col'];
```

I have tried multiple approaches including

```
return (mssql_fetch_assoc($result))['col'];
```

and

```
return mssql_fetch_assoc($result)['col'];
```

but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if you are on PHP >= 5.4.0, where this was implemented with the name [array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html).

Comment: Cool, thanks! Running PHP 5.3 tho, heard so much bad about PHP 5.4 from one Stefan Esser...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
function getvalue($array, $key)
{
  return $array[$key];
}
```

and then `return getvalue(mssql_fetch_assoc($result),'col');`

Comment: Yeah. Even tho that one takes one extra function. Very creative tho!